# 403 forbidden error after adding a CDN

Tags: cname-record, cdn, forbidden, alibaba-cloud

Previously, http://www.funfun.org.cn worked in my browser.

Then, I decided to add a CDN on top of it. So I added a `CNAME` for `www.funfun.org.cn` to `funfun.org.cn.w.kunluncan.com`. As a result, `ping www.funfun.org.cn` showed well

```
PING funfun.org.cn.w.kunluncan.com (117.131.204.76): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 117.131.204.76: icmp_seq=0 ttl=38 time=47.667 ms
...
```

However, `http://www.funfun.org.cn` returned `403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access the URL on this server. Powered by Tengine`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**Edit 1:**

In the origin server, `sudo ufw status` returns:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: What did you set as the origin for the CDN? What is the origin? 403 means that something is listening on port 80 and understand HTTP but refuses to communicate with you due to a permissions issue.

Comment: The origin for the CDN is `118.190.151.166`.  I just added the status of `ufw` to the OP. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Add to your question: 1) What is the origin? (not its IP address) 2) Post your security group settings 3) Post your CDN setup. The more information that you provide the easier to figure this out.